# PHP foreach not saving all data from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, elgg

I'm pulling data from JSON array in php.
Everything works as expected but somewhere in the loop parts gets lost, it only pulls first one.
Please help.
Thank you very much.

Here is Json:

```
$json = '
{
    "theId": "fB17",
    "loadId": "82387T",
    "description": "Short description",
    "contact": "Name of person",
    "contactinfo": "Phone number or email of contact person",
    "pickupaddress": "Address",
    "parts": [
        { "number": "655-2032B" },
        { "number": "655-2056" },
        { "number": "655-2056" },
        { "number": "300-85091" }
    ]
}';
```

PHP code:

```
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $theId .= $data->theId;
    $loadId .= $data->loadId;
    $description .= $data->description;
    $contact .= $data->contact;
    $contactinfo .= $data->contactinfo;
    $pickupaddress .= $data->pickupaddress;

    ALL ABOVE GET PULLED FROM JSON AND SAVED PROPERLY
```

Saving data

```
    $obj = new ElggObject();
    $obj->subtype = "load";
    $obj->description = strip_tags($description);
    $obj->title = $title.$theId.'-'.$loadId;
    $obj->contact = $contact;
    $obj->contactinfo = $contactinfo;
    $obj->pickupaddress = $pickupaddress;

    $guid = $obj->save();
```

Object is saved with basic info

Now going through "parts" data from Json

```
foreach ($data->parts as $core_title) {

    // Getting "parts' value from Json
    $titlename = $core_title->number;

    //Now need to use that data and find existing entity with that title in Database

    $dbprefix = elgg_get_config('dbprefix');

    $options['joins'][] = "JOIN {$dbprefix}objects_entity oe ON oe.guid = e.guid";
    $options['wheres'][] = "oe.title = '$titlename'";
    $options['types'] = array('object');
    $options['subtypes'] = array('core');
    $options['limit'] = 1;

    $entity = elgg_get_entities($options);
    // I got that entity that matches the title

    //Now get GUID of the entity
    foreach ($entity as $o) {
        $boxg = $o->guid;
    }

    // It works I get the GUID as $boxg but now need to save EACH $data->parts as annotation to database

    $obj->annotate('cores', $boxg);
}
```

IT only grabs first one fron Json ( 655-2032B )and saves only that one.

If I do this it saves each $data->parts value not just first one:

```
foreach ($data->parts as $core_title) {
    $titlename = $core_title->number;

    $obj->annotate('cores', $titlename);
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is not guilty. The error probably is in `$obj->annotate('cores', $titlename);`. It is invoked for each element from the `parts` array and only you know how the `ElggObject::annotate()` method looks like.

Comment: Where exactly do you save the `parts` ? Is this inside the `annotate()` method? If so, then what's the difference between passing `$titlename` and passing `$boxg` to the method?

Comment: @axiac $obj->annotate('cores', $titlename); creates annotations in database for main $obj but it saves only first one does not get all 4 that are in Json.

Comment: @Matey parts array pulls the title (number from Json) then with that I search existing entities that has matching title with `$entity = elgg_get_entities($options);` and once it is found I need to get GUID of entity (I get that with `$boxg = $o->guid;`) so each $data->parts has to go through that process and then I need to annotate each one with GUID of found entity which is `$boxg`. So it seems that `$obj->annotate('cores', $titlename);` needs to go somewhere else or in its own foraech?

Comment: Thing that makes me believe it is my foreach loops is because if I only use this:

`foreach ($data->parts as $core_title) {
    $attachment = $core_title->number;  

    $obj->annotate('cores', $attachment);
    }`

it creates annotation with each number as value. (655-2032B, 655-2056 and 300-85091)

But I need to find object that has title as each number first and then annotate with GUID of that object for each number.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense:

```
//Now get GUID of the entity
foreach ($entity as $o) {
    $boxg = $o->guid;
}
```

It goes through all items in `$entity` and keeps overwriting `$boxg` value without actually doing anything with the value.

The result of this foreach loop is that `$boxg` holds the GUID of the last item in `$entity` and only then this one single value used to annotate:

```
    $obj->annotate('cores', $boxg);
```

Is this what you really wanted to do? Shouldn't the annotate method be used inside the foreach loop?

Apart from that it's hard to give you a clear answer because your code is rather obscure and not well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally.
It was not foreach but what was in it.

Ended up making function that does database query to find existing entity with that title.

This is what I ended up with.
Thanks everyone for the help.

```
foreach ($data->parts as $core_title) {

    $titlename = $core_title->number;

    $entity = get_object_by_title('core',$titlename);

    foreach ($entity as $o) { 
    $coreguidd = $o->guid; 
    $obj->annotate('cores', $coreguidd);
    }


    }
```